# Shooting and Newton–Raphson methods for plotting nonlinear frequency-amplitude diagram (Nonlinear Vibration)

Tags: numerical-integration

[image]The aim is plotting frequency-amplitude diagram for the Duffing equation using. Using the shooting we first reach the periodic motion and get the result for only one period.  Using the newton method we correct the initial guess to reach the periodic motion. Finally  employing the Floquet theory, the stable and unstable branches can be obtained.
A deep detail is observable in the book "MEMS Linear and Nonlinear Statics and Dynamics", Written by Mohammad I.Younis.
Best regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure what you want but possibly [this question and answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202282/12558) is what you are thinking about.  Is this correct?

Comment: Dear @Hugh
The link that you mentioned is correct. But, I want to plot such a diagram using the shooting method.

Comment: You do have to shoot. You keep shooting until you get a periodic solution. To make the shooting converge on a periodic solution the link uses `FindRoot`.  You shoot until the initial condition equals the final condition.